# Coding Challenge: Kattis

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

**Short problem description:**

> A sequence of numbers are antiarithemtic if there exists no three
>   numbers `a_i`, `a_j`, `a_k` – where `a_i` preceeds `a_j` which then again
>   preceeds `a_k` in the sequence – such that `a_i - a_j = a_j - a_k`.
>   Example: (5, 0, -1, 3, 1) is **not** antiarithemtic, because 5-3 =
>   3-1, wheras the sequence (1, 5, 3, 0, -1) **is** antiarithemtic.

Link to the [Kattis page](https://open.kattis.com/problems/antiarithmetic).

My attempt:

```
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
lines = [x[:-1] for x in lines]
for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        line = line.split(':')
        found = False
        visited = {}
        curr = line[1].split()
        r = len(curr)
        for i in range(r):
            visited_2 = {}
            if curr[i] in visited:
                continue
            else:
                visited[curr[i]] = True
                for j in range(i+1, r):
                    if curr[j] in visited_2:
                        continue
                    else:
                        visited_2[curr[j]] = True
                        tmp = int(curr[i]) - int(curr[j])
                        for k in range(j+1, r):
                            if int(curr[j]) - int(curr[k]) == tmp:
                                print("no")
                                found = True
                                break
        if not found:
            print("yes")
    else:
        break
```

I believe my attempt solves the problem of finding out whether a sequence is antiarithmetic or not, as I've made my own extensive example-set to test that. My optimizing step so far has been to include dictionaries of visited "nodes" so as to not repeat searches for numbers that we already know do not result in an arithmetic sequence. However, it is not fast enough for Kattis, so I would much appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

making your code harder to read:

- lack of docstrings
- lack of comments
- unwarranted indentation using an `else:` after a "disruptive `if`" 
  (transferring execution with return, break, continue)
  (Here, you are using this with otherwise empty "`if`-parts":
  you could negate the conditions and just use the former `else:`-statements. Hello again, indentation.)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will clean up the code some time tomorrow when I have some free time. I didn't bother with it at first, thought maybe someone would see something that I've done wrong conceptually either way. But thank you, you are absolutely right.

Comment: (I belatedly noticed one more incidence of *avoidable indentation* right in the outer loop: you could use `if len(line) <= 0: break;`) If you are going to change the code more than a trifle/in any aspect mentioned by answers, ask a new question and cross-link unless you delete this one altogether.